# javascript datastructure question

Tags: javascript, data-structures, object

I have an array:

```
myArray = [];
```

To which I am adding objects:

```
data = [];

myArray.push( {
  elem1: ...,
  elem2: data.push(...);
} );
```

So, `elem2` in the object contains an array.  How can I, given `myArray` add new elements to the array in `elem2`?  I tried the following:

```
myArray[idx].elem2.push("new data");
```

But got an error saying that elem2.push() is not a method.

Comment: Did you try to set elem2 to be array()?

Answer (score 2):

The issue line is:

```
elem2: data.push(...)
```

*data* is an array.  The push method for arrays does not return the array, it returns the *length* of the array once the item has been added.

So if you have:

```
var data = [];

var moreData = data.push(1);
```

*moreData* will actually equal *1*.

Since the value of *elem2* is actually an integer, you are then calling push on that integer.  That's where you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

The `.push()` function does not return the array, so that line that tries to set "elem2", well it isn't doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same and works, look the code:

```
var a = [];
a.push({

  a: []

});

a[0].a.push("a");

alert(a[0].a[0]); // return 'a'
```

in your array you must add another array, not the array.push(), because it will return the position that elements was inserted.